# Full height div: make faux column have a fixed width

Tags: css, html

I have a layout like so:

```
<div class='foo'>
    <div class='bar'>
        <div class='baz'>
            Content stuff...<br/>
            Content stuff...<br/>
            Content stuff...<br/>
            Content stuff...<br/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

with CSS like so:

```
.foo{
    position:absolute;
    left:20px;
    top:20px;
}
.bar{
    width:0px;
    border-left:1px solid blue;
    border-right:1px solid yellow;
}
.baz{
    padding-left:35px;
    padding-right:27px;
}
```

... a pretty standard way to get a full height columns. But I also need `bar` to be a fixed width (in this case 0px). Is there any way to get the content div, `baz`, to have its old width (when `bar` had auto width), and still keep `bar` full height?

Comment: What do you mean "a pretty standard way to get a full height columns"? This column is spanned by the contents inside it. What's "full height" about that?

Comment: As a reference this technique: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS alone, I don't think so; At least none I can't think of.

Why not set the width to auto in CSS, using jQuery you can set the width to a variable, and then you can set the width to 0px...

That way you've got a variable that you can set .baz to.

Am I making sense?

Comment: Yeah. Right now, I'm just resorting to a JavaScript method. It would be nice to find a way to get full height div's when you need them for more than just background-faking.